# Is there any way in Django Rest framework serializer for ignoring case in choice field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  contract = fields.ChoiceField(choices=(
    ('no', 'no'),
    ('yes', 'yes'),
  ))
```

So here my input can be one of the following.
no, No,Yes,yes

for these do I need to add 2 more entry for Capital one?

```
contract = fields.ChoiceField(choices=(
    ('no', 'no'),
    ('yes', 'yes'),
    ('No', 'no'),
    ('Yes', 'yes'),

  ))
```

or is there any way by which we can ignore the case?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield

If you want to leave it to user, you might have to think of more options like "yes", "Yes", "YES" instead of just "yes, "Yes"

I prefer you convert them to lower and set it on the field by using .lower(), so that you will always get lowercase letters as input